# Best way to find non intersecting elements of array

Tags: java

I have 2 arrays of User Objects.
1 array contains list of all users
and 2nd array contains list of all logged in Users.
Which is the best way to find non-logged in users

Comment: That's called a set difference. Are the arrays sorted? Otherwise I'd recommend you to use a `HashSet`.

Comment: @LMD- Arrays are not sorted

Comment: [java.util.Collection#removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: Is it possible to do it without collections? and without linear search in Array?

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases:

1. If you do not have equals and hash code methods implemented in User:

then the simplest way would be to get all UserIdentifier, like databaseId or username. Persist it in a hashed structure, for fast search. Then go through all Users and accept all not contained in this collection.

Create a set of logged user Identifiers:

```
 Set<Long> loggedUserIdentifiers = loggedUsers.stream()
                                   .map(User::getId) // I have chosen Id
                                   .collect(toSet());
```

Now you can find all not-logged users:

```
 List<User> unloggedUsers = allUsers.stream()
                            .filter( user -> !loggedUserIdentifiers.contains(user.getId()))
                            .collect(toSet());
```

2. If you have equals and hash code implemented, then you could simply remove all logged users from a copy of all Users collection. Just remember to create a copy first, otherwise You will end with only logged and not-logged Users.

   ```
   Set<User> allUserCopy = new HashSet<>(allUsers); // works on lists also
   allUserCopy.removeAll(loggedUsers);
   Set<User> notLoggedUsers = Set.copyOf(allUserCopy);
   ```

Now you will have a collection with only not logged users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to do it without collections? and without linear search in Array?

Comment: @ravi There is no linear search involved here (rather a set lookup is used), only looping over all users to find all non-logged-in ones.